# How to put JSON data from server with GridView --Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I had referred to the cookbook.

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

The sample code is to get single JSON data.

I'm trying to get following multiple JSON data from StatefulWidget.
And I would like to show season data in each grid by GridView.

```
[
  {"id":1,"season_end":"1999/01","season_name":"First","season_start":"1999/08"}, 
  {"id":2,"season_end":"1999/07","season_name":"Second","season_start":"1999/02"}, 
  {"id":3,"season_end":"2000/01","season_name":"Third","season_start":"1999/08"}, 
  {"id":4,"season_end":"2000/07","season_name":"Forth","season_start":"2000/02"}
]
```

However I have no idea to write better code like below.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Future<List<Season>> seasons;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    seasons = fetchSeasons();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            ...
          ),
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return seasons[index].toString();
          }
      )
    )
  }
}
```

I should have used `FutureBuilder<List<Season>>`, But I don't know how to use with `GridView`.
Do you have any advice? Please.

```
Future<List<Season>> fetchSeasons() async {
  final response =
  await http.get('http://10.0.2.2:4000/api/seasons');

  if(response.statusCode == 200){
    Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
    var seasons = list.map((season) => Season.fromJson(season)).toList();
    return seasons;
  }else{
    print('Error!!');
    throw Exception('Failed to Load Post');
  }
}
```

```
class Season {
  final int id;
  final String season_name;
  final String season_start;
  final String season_end;

  Season({this.id, this.season_name, this.season_start, this.season_end});

  factory Season.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return Season(
      id: json['id'],
      season_name: json['season_name'],
      season_start: json['season_start'],
      season_end: json['season_end']
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `seasons` is a `Future`, not a `List`, that's why you can't use it like a list.

If you want to access the list of that `Future`, you need to use `FutureBuilder`, like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: FutureBuilder<List<Season>>(
      future: seasons,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return GridView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              ...
              ),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Text("${snapshot.data[index].season_name}");
              }
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Error");
        }
        return Text("Loading...");
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of ways to do that with [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) you can do like this,in this case you dont need to use initstate or a Stateful widget the futurebuilder automatically calls the method `fetchSeasons()` as it gets rendered on screen and the result is received as a snapshot which can be accessed as below.

```
FutureBuilder<List<seasons>>(
future:fetchSeasons(),
builder:(BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot <List<seasons>>snapshot){
          snapshot.hasData?
          return GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            ...
          ),
          itemCount:snapshot.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return Column(
             children: <Widget>[
                    Text('${snapshot.data[index]['id']}'),
                    Text('${snapshot.data[index]['season_name']}'),
                    Text('${snapshot.data[index]['season_end']}'),
                    Text('${snapshot.data[index]['season_start']}'),
                ]
               ):Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand why the number of grids is more than 4? It returns more grids and have out of index.

Comment: Ops. I forget set itemCount. Sorry.

Comment: Text('${snapshot.data[index]['season_name']}', has error. The operator [] isn't defined for the class Season. Actually it has.

Comment: so Basically it seems that fetchSeasons() is not returning a list